# When I try to redirect one of two twilio connected calls to a conference, the call moves to the conference but ends within 2 seconds

Tags: api, rest, queue, twilio

The basic issue I am facing is "When I try to redirect one of two connected calls (each is a twilio generated call) to a conference, the call moves to the conference but ends within 2 seconds"

Here are the steps,
1. Customer calls and is put in queue
2. A REST API twilio call is created to agent phone
3. When agent picks up the call then we are queueing into the queue where customer call is present from first step and connects the agent with the queued call (throught  twiml)
4. Then through REST api I am trying to put the callsid for customer call to a conference. On doing this the caller is put in conference but after 2 seconds the customer calls ends.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Are there more than 2 participants in your scenario or do you want to simply connect the agent to the customer?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are saying that after 2 seconds the customer call ends, I suspect that some Customer call `status callback` or `action` URL is hit that executes a `hangup` action.

It could be the `action` URL on the `enqueue` verb (used to put the customer into queue) that is executed and returns the `hangup`. The action would be executed when de-queued call ends (or being forwarded to a conference).

That would be my guess.

That being said, it is not clear why do you need to put the Agent and the Customer to the conference? Once the Agent calls into Queue, he connects to the Customer and they can begin talking.

Comment: "Since you are saying that after 2 seconds the customer call ends, I suspect that some Customer call status callback or action URL is hit that executes a hangup action."


It's only after the call is picked up by the agent and that the control goes to action url and then we are queueing into the call and both get connected.

Comment: "It could be the action URL on the enqueue verb (used to put the customer into queue) that is executed and returns the hangup. The action would be executed when de-queued call ends (or being forwarded to a conference)."

I had checked this and it was not affecting that.

Comment: "That being said, it is not clear why do you need to put the Agent and the Customer to the conference? Once the Agent calls into Queue, he connects to the Customer and they can begin talking."

Both the agent and customer are connected from queue then I want to transfer the customer to another call and before that we are putting into conference call for a few.

Comment: I had to implement the same scenario. If I recall correctly, I have concluded that Twilio does not support directing calls from queue to conference. I could not explain the issues I had and you are having otherwise.
How I did solve the issue though was to use a new queue instead of the conference. So you can create a queue for the second agent and forward the call to that queue. Then de-queue that call as usual and it should work.

Comment: Alvis, it is after both agent and customer queue call connect that I am redirecting customer call to conference. So I think it should not be in queue any more while I am redirecting into conference.

Comment: Yes, that was my case as well. The agent and customer queue call connects, they talk for some time and then the customer call needs to be redirected to another agent. I have used a new enqueue for the second agent. The second agent de-queues the call from it's (second) queue and the customer can successfully talk to the second agent.

Comment: By the way, if you have found a different solution, please share it with me, I would be interested to know how to accomplish this using conference.